# is there a way of making NavigationView take less code (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, navigation-drawer

I'm somewhat considered a (Kotlin beginner) and current working on a task, and my `NavDrawer` takes too much space in each page. I have my own `Header content` and `Menu Items` ready but if I want to include it in every page it takes too much space and having to update each `drawer` content everytime I edit it will be very time consuming! Is there any way I can possibly make one place where it holds all my `NavDarwer` code and then just include it in other pages? thanks for reading and appreciate any suggestions

Edit-

nav code:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" />
```

The code in MainActivity for Navigation:

```
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.nav_latestAds -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You are currently here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            R.id.nav_cars -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Messages clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            R.id.nav_properties -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Friends clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            R.id.nav_mobiles -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Update clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            R.id.nav_electDev -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sign out clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            R.id.nav_furniture -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sign out clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            R.id.nav_customerReg -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sign out clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            R.id.nav_vendorReg -> {
                val intent = Intent(this, RegisterVendor::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            R.id.nav_logout -> {
                if (AuthService.isLoggedIn) {
                    UserDataService.logout()
                    Menu_userName.text = "User name"
                } else {
                    val loginIntent = Intent(this, Login::class.java)
                    startActivity(loginIntent)
                }
            }
        }
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        return true
    }
```

the issue here is the if I want to add the NavigationView in each page, itll take a lot of code space. So I'm wondering if there is any way I can maybe make a shortcut to place the entire Navigation code in one place and pass it to the other pages.

Latest edit-

```
package com.example.wasit

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity
import com.example.wasit.Model.Login
import com.example.wasit.Model.RegisterVendor
import com.example.wasit.Services.AuthService
import com.example.wasit.Services.UserDataService

class NavigationHandler (val context: Context,val menuItem: MenuItem){
    operator fun invoke() {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.nav_latestAds -> {
                Toast.makeText(context, "You are currently here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            R.id.nav_cars -> {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Messages clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            R.id.nav_properties -> {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Friends clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            R.id.nav_mobiles -> {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Update clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            R.id.nav_electDev -> {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Sign out clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            R.id.nav_furniture -> {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Sign out clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            R.id.nav_customerReg -> {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Sign out clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            R.id.nav_vendorReg -> {
                val intent = Intent(context, RegisterVendor::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            R.id.nav_logout -> {
                if (AuthService.isLoggedIn) {
                    UserDataService.logout()
                    Menu_userName.text = "User name"
                } else {
                    val loginIntent = Intent(context, Login::class.java)
                    startActivity(loginIntent)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some code please?

Comment: Check after "Edit-" @SaeedEntezari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the code to another class and just pass the dependencies it needs:

```
class NavigationHandler(val context: Context, val menuItem: MenuItem){
    operator fun invoke() {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.nav_latestAds -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You are currently here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            R.id.nav_cars -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Messages clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            R.id.nav_properties -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Friends clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            R.id.nav_mobiles -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Update clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            R.id.nav_electDev -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sign out clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            R.id.nav_furniture -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sign out clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            R.id.nav_customerReg -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sign out clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            R.id.nav_vendorReg -> {
                val intent = Intent(this, RegisterVendor::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            R.id.nav_logout -> {
                if (AuthService.isLoggedIn) {
                    UserDataService.logout()
                    Menu_userName.text = "User name"
                } else {
                    val loginIntent = Intent(this, Login::class.java)
                    startActivity(loginIntent)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    NavigationHandler(context, item)()
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    return true
}
```

Comment: Sorry yeah I just realized that, but all the toasts are giving me errors and the intent codes as well now, also item is never called so i switched it with menuItem and still gave errors

Comment: replace this with context please.

Comment: got an error in startActivity it says mismatch its looking for Intent but found Context

Comment: @ChipChocolate Change startActivity to context.startActivity(intent)

Comment: Thank you! :) its working now, my apologies for not quite understanding well im kinda new to kotlin so really appreciate it

Comment: @ChipChocolate No problem :) You can read this page (and pointed section) to learn more about this: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#invoke

Comment: theres just this 1 error left that im unable to solve, Menu_userName.text = "User name" tried fixing it but been having issues